# Getting GraphicDeviceManager from another class

Tags: c#, graphics, xna

I've been searching for a way to use the GraphicDeviceManager in other classes that don't inherit from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game

I'm using the Game State Management example.

I've got a class called "FirstLevel" which is essentialy GamePlayScreen from the example, I'm trying to get that class to use the GraphicsDeviceManager to do code such as the following;

```
        this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1920;
        this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1080;
```

But it has no idea what "graphics" actually is.

What are my options in terms of getting a hold of a GraphicsDeviceManager and using it in the FirstLevel class?

I can't inherit from Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game because my class is already inheriting from GameScreen.

I heard somwhere that you can use the DrawableGameComponent class to access a GraphicsDeviceManager, such as the class "ScreenManager" which inherits from this class.

I cant pass Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game into the constructor of firstLevel because other classes that call it need to get the GraphicsDeviceManager to pass into it.

Any help guys?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The usual is passing to your GameScreen constructor the game instance as a Game parameter.

A GraphicDeviceManager is used to initializate graphics, inside a game you should use the GraphicsDevice instance provided by the game instance.

```
public class GameScreen {

    public Game Game;
    public GameScreen(Game game) {
        this.Game = game;
    }   

    public void Update()
    {
       Game.GraphicsDevice....
    }                                
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the advice, I ended up passing "Game game" into practically all my classes to get it to work error free, thanks very much